# C programming struct pointers

Tags: pointers, struct

how can i continue this function to search the int_set array for 'item' and return true/ false? I don't know how to work with pointers as arguments to a function

```
struct int_set {
       int * array;
       int max_elements;
       int current_elements;
};
```

//function

```
int int_set_search(struct int_set * ptr, int item){};
```

Comment: Why don't you take a stab at it and then come back with a more specific question when you run into trouble?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int int_set_search(struct int_set * ptr, int item)
{
   for(int i=0; i < ptr->max_elements; ++i)
   {
       if (ptr->array[i] == item) 
       {  // Found it!
          return TRUE;
       }
   }
   return FALSE;
}
```